# How can I set SASS to ignore certain folders in static directory (Express)

Tags: node.js, express, sass

## Question

How can I make `node-sass-middleware` ignore everything else in the static folder, except for what is in the scss directory?

## Background

I'm new to Express/Node and SASS. I want to define my static folder to have SCSS files that are auto-compiled, but also have CSS files that just sit there and aren't touched by `node-sass-middleware`

The problem is, `node-sass-middleware` is expecting that every CSS file in my static folder should have a corresponding SCSS file.

## Express Setup

```
var express = require('express');
var sass = require('node-sass-middleware');
var app = express();
app.use(
    sass({
        src: __dirname + '/assets/scss',
        dest: __dirname + '/assets',
        debug: true,
    })
);
app.use(express.static('assets'));
```

## Folder Structure

```
-assets
--css
--scss
--static
---css
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be  `'/assets/scss'`?

Comment: That was just a typo when writing the question, question is now updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure how much sense it makes to put `.css` files in your `scss` folder. Can't you just keep the `.css` files in your `assets/static/css` folder? And then you can change your `dest` to `assets/static/css` as well.

And then you would want to change you're `express.static` to `app.use(express.static('assets/static'));`

Comment: Thank you, being new to both Express and SCSS/SASS, I have no idea what makes sense. One thing that doesn't make sense to me is that it by default looks for a `scss/css` folder when loading source files, even though I didn't set that as the source directory.