# JavaScript isn't accessible inside the static folder when using sass/scss

Tags: javascript, express, sass

## Question

JavaScript isn't accessible inside the static folder when using `sass/scss`. How can I configure it to allow me to either put my JavaScript files somewhere that `sass/css` doesn't care about, or make the current folder structure work?

I should be able to access the below mentioned `script.js` file at `localhost:3000/js/script.js`, just like I can access `localhost:3000/css/style.css`.

## Background

I just recently got the `node-sass-middleware` working. You can see my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34124507/how-can-i-set-sass-to-ignore-certain-folders-in-static-directory-express). Unfortunately, now my JavaScript doesn't work. Disabling `node-sass-middleware` makes Javascript accessible inside the `assets/static/js` folder. I imagine it has something to do with the fact that sass is putting its output into `assets/static/css`. I just can't figure it out!

## Express Setup

```
var express = require('express');
var sass = require('node-sass-middleware');
var app = express();
app.use(
    sass({
        src: __dirname + '/assets/scss',
        dest: __dirname + '/assets/static',
        debug: true,
    })
);
app.use(express.static('/assets/static'));
```

## Folder Structure

```
-assets
--scss
---style.css
--static
---css
----style.css (compiled)
---js
----script.js (not accessible, unless I remove node-sass-middleware)
app.js (express app)
```

Comment: Shouldn't the `dest` folder for your sass be `dest: __dirname + '/assets/static/css'`?

Comment: If I do that, then it looks for `/assets/static/css/css`.

Comment: Setting that to be `/assets/static/css` fixes the problem of javascript not working, but now the generated css is inside `/assets/static/css/css/`. My inclusion of the css file is as follows: `link(rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css")`

Comment: What does this have to do with Sass?  Sass doesn't care about anything other than where you put your Sass files.

Comment: If you read my post, you'd see that my code isn't broken when I exclude sass. Clearly I have a configuration issue with sass. How about some constructive feedback?